# kivy buildozer создание apk

Tags: python, kivy, apk

Существуют ли сервисы для создания apk файлов из .py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, таких сервисов не существует.

Answer (score 0):

ЕСТЬ ТАКАЯ ПРОГРАММА!

Она работает на линукс и только в консоли

Называется **buildozer**

Вот, [ознакомьтесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/479236/).

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).